# Highcharts reflow changes height

Tags: highcharts

As part of my debugging, I've got to the stage where all I'm calling is `reflow()` on my highchart - nothing else changes before calling this method - it is the only thing happening on a button click.

```
<div id="chart" class="chart"></div> // <== highchart created in here by JS code
....
// in button click handler
var chart = $("#chart").highcharts();
chart.reflow();
```

When this method is invoked, the height of the (Highcharts-created) element:

```
<div class="highcharts-container" id="highcharts-0"</div>
```

increases (by 30px in this instance) every time it is called.

Why does this happen, and how can I stop/undo this action?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to add the code for your chart? That way, we can test it out to see where the problem is occurring. Thank you!

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo on the jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I managed a workaround - note its height, reflow it, calculate the increase, subtract it (twice - once from the reflow, and once more for the next),
then reflow it again. Messy, but it works....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when calling `reflow()` alone.

You can easily fix this issue by setting a fixed height to the chart container `<div class="chart">`.

```
.chart {
   height: 400px;
}
```